# Unable to find a radio button in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am unable to select radio button in Selenium Webdriver-Java with given html code

```
<input id="idcc-de81e53f-7cfd-4136-816f-d09d4055eeee" type="radio" value="de81e53f-7cfd-4136-816f-d09d4055eeee" name="panels:0:panel:stepContainer:stepTypeDisplay:optionPanel:options">
<label for="idcc-de81e53f-7cfd-4136-816f-d09d4055eeee">Canada</label>
<br>
<input id="idcc-17c1d432-5cec-4da9-9a02-39986d508770" type="radio" value="17c1d432-5cec-4da9-9a02-39986d508770" name="panels:0:panel:stepContainer:stepTypeDisplay:optionPanel:options">
<label for="idcc-17c1d432-5cec-4da9-9a02-39986d508770">United States</label>
```

Comment: Did you mean to post some code? I can't see any.

Comment: plz post the source code for the question

Comment: WebElement radioButtonCanada=driver.findElement(By.id("idcc-de81e53f-7cfd-4136-816f-d09d4055eeee"));
      radioButtonCanada.click();
   
   //united States
   WebElement radioButtonUS=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[contains(@text, 'United States')]"));
   radioButtonUS.click();

Answer (score 0):

`id="idcc-de81e53f-7cfd-4136-816f-d09d4055eeee"` most likely to by dynamic id so what you need to do is something like

**option 1:**

```
List<WebElement> radioButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']"));

foreach(IWebElement button : radioButtons)
{
   if(button.getText.Equels("Canada"))
   {
      button.cilck();
   }
}
```

**option 2:**

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Canada")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi please do it like below

```
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/rajnish/Desktop/radio.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
// for canada
driver.findElement(By.id("idcc-de81e53f-7cfd-4136-816f-d09d4055eeee")).click();

// for United states
driver.findElement(By.id("idcc-17c1d432-5cec-4da9-9a02-39986d508770")).click();
```

what issues you were facing in doing this its very simple and straight ,please post your sample code that you have tried so that i can help you were you were doing it wrong thanks